# Move the Android Status Bar

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to move the status bar in Android (Froyo) from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen.  I have done a lot of research but haven't found anyone who was successfully able to do this.

Side notes: I don't want to hide the status bar, I want to move it.  Also, I'm not concerned if the status bar can no longer be expanded.  For this use case, it will never need to be.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Looked at the status_bar.xml file in `systemui/res/status_bar.xml` but it only seems to define the layout WITHIN the status bar and not the status bar itself.
2. Looked at `systemui\src\com\android\systemui\statusbar\StatusBarService.java` file.

   - Around line 267, a `StatusBarView` is created from R.layout.status_bar (defined in the status_bar.xml file I referred to in above).
   - Around line 330, a `WindowManager.LayoutParams` is instantiated and the gravity is set to `Gravity.TOP`.
   - The view and the WindowManager.LayoutParams are passed to  `WindowManagerImpl.getDefault().addView(view, lp)` on line 341 at the end of addStatusBarView().

Based on this, I changed the gravity of the WindowManager.LayoutParams to Gravity.BOTTOM.  This **DID** work to some extent; the status bar is at the bottom of the screen.  However, everything else that would normally be displayed underneath the status bar is still underneath the status bar - it gets pushed off the bottom of the screen.  It's as if the rest of the screen is positioned relative to the status bar.

Can anyone provide any insight on what else I need to modify for this to work?

Comment: can you provide the link to status_bar.xml?

Comment: @Aleadam This is the URL for status_bar.xml: [status_bar.xml](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=packages/SystemUI/res/layout/status_bar.xml;h=a5d6885c6b907037fd57606dc1708e722819fe68;hb=refs/heads/master)

Comment: I think you should be looking at all the math that defines mExpandedParams (i think its around lines 1343 and on.  Also follow the footsteps of performFling (around line 875)

Comment: @jkhouw1 Thanks for the reply but unless I'm mistaken, the code you're referring to is related to the process of expanding the status bar, not moving it.  I need to move the entire bar to the bottom, where it will never be expanded.

Comment: sorry i didn't see the part about not caring about the expansion: i thought you successfully moved the status bar and actually needed the expansion to expand UP to be above it. The only thing below the status bar is the icons & the rest of the main screen etc.. so all that gets pushed below it?

Comment: @jkhouw1 Yeah, I successfully moved the status bar to the bottom, but my problem now is that the rest of the main screen (everything else - icons, background, widgets, you name it) gets pushed off the screen below the status bar.  Essentially, I'm looking for a way of moving the "everything else" container so that it's positioned *above* the status bar instead of below it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this problem is as follows:

1. Around line 345 of `frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/status/StatusBarService.java` change `Gravity.TOP` to `Gravity.BOTTOM`.
2. Around line 1265 of `frameworks/policies/base/phone/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java` replace `mDockTop = mContentTop = mCurTop = mStatusBar.getFrameLw().bottom` with `mContentBottom = mCurBottom = mStatusBar.getFrameLw().top`.
3. Around line 719 of `frameworks/policies/base/mid/com/android/internal/policy/impl/MidWindowManager.java`, replace `mCurTop = mStatusBar.getFrameLw().bottom` with `mCurBottom = mStatusBar.getFrameLw().top`.

I tested this on Froyo in an emulator and it works fine.  The status bar is on the bottom, and everything else is above it.  As I mentioned above, for my use case, I will never need to expand the status bar, so this is sufficient for me. However, as @jkhouw1 mentioned,  it's possible that the status bar could be made to expand upwards by modifying the logic in `StatusBarService.java`, particularly the `performFling` method on line 1159.

Hope someone finds this useful!