# Move Android Status Bar in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a project to modify some of the UI elements on Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich.)  Specifically, I'm trying to reposition the status bar to the bottom of the screen.

I have found a post for doing something very similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971585/move-the-android-status-bar); however, the information is for Froyo and the source tree, not surprisingly, had diverged enough since then to render the information outdated (the referenced source files no longer appear to exist in the 4.0.3 AOSP.)

Does anyone have any information as to where the relevant source files to modify the status bar position now exist in the ICS AOSP and what changes are required to modify the status bar position?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about the Notification Bar (thing up top that you pull down that has signal strenght, notifications, etc) or the Action Bar (tabs, menu options)

Comment: I am referring to the Notification Bar.  I called it the Status Bar as that is what the Android developer documentation appears to refer to it as, but, yes, it's the UI that shows the signal strength, battery indicator, time, etc. and where notifications can be displayed

Answer (score 2):

As you have showed one link which tells the procedure for Froyo,In  ICS the StatusBarService.java file has been removed and the same code is present in StatusBar.java and the gravity has been obtained from `getStatusBarGravity()` method.You should be able to move your status bar to the bottom for Phone by changing the following in the PhoneStatusBar.java

```
protected int getStatusBarGravity() {
    return Gravity.TOP | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;
}
```

to

```
protected int getStatusBarGravity() {
        return Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL;
    }
```

This worked for me.

Thnaks 
Narayan