# Changing position of the status bar in the android ICS Framework

Tags: android, frameworks

I am new to android.I want to move my position of the android ICS status bar say 50 dp up from the bottom of the screen.(ie.layout_marginBottom=50dp).Where to do the modifications in the framework to get this done?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move Android Status Bar in Ice Cream Sandwich](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076872/move-android-status-bar-in-ice-cream-sandwich)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

For this after some digging into the StatusBar.java code,I have found the solution as follows:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                height,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_STATUS_BAR,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TOUCHABLE_WHEN_WAKING
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SPLIT_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.RGB_565);

//Line to be added 
    lp.y = 50;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Great you posted your answer there! I voted to close this question, as it's exactly the same as the question you mentioned. Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Actually for me,I dont want to change the gravity of my status bar instead want to change layout_maginBottom.For this after some digging into the StatusBar.java code,I have found the solution as follows:                                                         
                final Display defaultDisplay = ((WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
//Line to be added
 lp.y = 50;

Comment: Ah, that's useful info for others with the same question. Consider placing this in your answer. And note that you can accpet your own answer too, so that everybody knows your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice explained tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Here it is more about status_bar icons.I want something which explains about status bar itself.Thanks